# Shouldn't die() in php be able to print out numbers?

Tags: php, die

If I set

```
$myVar = "yay";
die($myVar);
```

that echos out yay, and kills the script.

However, if I set

```
$myVar = 2;
die($myVar);
```

nothing echos.

Why is that?

Cheers guys.

Comment: [`die()`](http://us1.php.net/die) is equivalent to `exit()`. Read the short documentation of [`exit()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to print an integer then simply cast it as a string

```
<?php
  $var = 1;
  # exit() or die()
  exit("".$var);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Directly from the PHP Manual, `die()` is the same as `exit()`, and `exit($status)` says this:

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

Comment: Cheers Helpful - I understand why die() was behaving the way it was now.